# ORA-00917-missing coma

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT 
    XMLELEMENT (
        DECODE ('RF', 'RF', 'Credit', 'Sale'), xmlattributes ('01234567' AS "id")
    ) AS Order
FROM 
    DUAL
```

When I run the above query I'm getting `ORA-00917-missing coma` error.

Comment: This, `DECODE ('RF', 'RF', 'Credit', 'Sale')` is really pointless. You're checking the string `RF`. If it's `RF` (always true) then replace it with `Credit` otherwise `Sale`. You might just as well write `Credit` in there and leave it as-is. Or, is RF meant to be a column? In which case remove the inverted commas.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if you want a dynamic element name, you need to use `EVALNAME`

```
SELECT 
    XMLELEMENT (
          evalname(       
        DECODE ('RF', 'RF', 'Credit', 'Sale')),
      xmlattributes ('01234567' AS "id")
    ).getstringval() AS "Order"
FROM 
    DUAL
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8399)

Comment: If Refund order then the tag should be Credit else Sale

My Requirement is like this 
    <Credit>
     <id="01234567">
     <OrderType>RF</OrderType>
     </Credit>
    <Sale >
    <id="01234567">
    <OrderType>NF</OrderType>
    </Sale>

Comment: @ChaitanyaKandukuri that's what A.B.Cade showed you. to add OrderType its simple, just add an `xmlforest` eg: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8410

Comment: @ChaitanyaKandukuri, a- How does your table look like? b- this is not a valid XML - Can't have an element like this `<id="01234567">`. Did you mean something like this? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68902/2

Comment: Hi 
I'm trying to create a XML output file by creating a procedure and use that procedure for a concurrent request .
Please find the below package-procedure code .But now it is errored out with 
"Cause:  FDPSTP failed due to ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-22806: not an object or REF"

Comment: below code of the program is giving error
XMLELEMENT(
                evalname(Decode((select ORDER_TYPE FROM My_orders WHERE order_id = mo.order_id),''RF'',''Credit'',''Sale'')).getstringval(),
                            XMLFOREST (mo.order_id AS "orderId",
                                        mo.amount AS "amount",'
                                        || '''ecommerce'''
                                        || ' AS "orderSource"
                                        ))

Comment: @ChaitanyaKandukuri, It's hard to read from comments... Update your original post

Comment: Hi I have added new Question : pls refer to that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228526/ora-22806-not-an-object-or-ref-error-while-generating-xml-output