# Concurrent program failed in executing DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file

Tags: xml, oracle

Oracle apps custom concurrent program is hanging at the statement DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2files and error out after some time.

we are using the program to generate a XML file.
the code would be something like the below.
([ORA-22806: not an object or REF : error while generating XML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228526/ora-22806-not-an-object-or-ref-error-while-generating-xml-output))

the below statement was not executing
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (lc_xml_clob, gfilelocation, gfilename, 0);

can anyone please help me .

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Hi
We found that , there is issue in the data format.
and we excluded that and it worked.

thanks